# android.R.id.home is not working in BottomAppbar in My Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to create Navigation View in Bottom App bar in Activity but android.R.id.home doesn't work . I have set the BottomAppbar object as setSupportActionBar(mBottomAppBar) but doesn't work

```
mBottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.emp_menu_home:
                        setFragment(empHomeFragment);
                        break;
                    case R.id.emp_menu_notif:
                        setFragment(notificationsFragment);
                        break;
                    case R.id.emp_menu_Inbox:
                        setFragment(inboxFragment);
                        break;
                    case R.id.emp_menu_cv:
                        setFragment(cvFragment);
                        break;
                    case android.R.id.home:

                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Home is click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        NaviDrawerFragment naviDrawerFragment=new NaviDrawerFragment();
                        naviDrawerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),naviDrawerFragment.getTag());
                        break;

                    default:
                        return false;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: If it's set as the support `ActionBar`, then a click on `android.R.id.home` will call the `Activity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` method with that ID, not the `Toolbar` listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: setHasOptionsMenu(true); in your onCreate().

or

If you're using the new Toolbar and ActionbarDrawerToggle. You can assign clickHandler directly. For my activities that have this drawer toolbar I implemented an interface to enable drawer if at root,

```
    @Override
    public void enableDrawer(boolean enable) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(enable);
        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// Pop fragment back stack or pass in a custom click handler from the fragment.
            }
        });
    }
```